# How to create a route based BottomNavigation component?

Tags: nativescript, bottomnavigationview, nativescript-vue

BottomNavigation component requires to put all tab contents on same page.

e.g:

```html
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Label text="Home Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Label text="Account Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
```

I think pages are loaded like a dynamic component. I want to have tabs only with route links. When user tap a tab, I will redirect user to another page.

If I don't use `TabContentItem`, `TabStripItems` are also not shown on page. So, I added them with empty contents.

Using `selectedIndexChange` event I can redirect user to another page, but when one of the tab links is current page, it goes to infinite loop.

It seems like tabs has to be on a different page on this setup. This is not something I want.

Is there a way to convert the BottomNavigation component to a route based one?

Here my current code is:
(It is a Vue project.)

```html
<template>
    <BottomNavigation selectedIndex="0" @selectedIndexChange="indexChange">
    <TabStrip @itemTap="test">
        <template v-for="(tab, key) in tabs">
        <TabStripItem :key="key">
            <Label :text="tab.title"></Label>
        </TabStripItem>
        </template>
    </TabStrip>
    <template v-for="(tab, key) in tabs">
        <TabContentItem :key="key">
        <GridLayout>
        </GridLayout>
        </TabContentItem>
    </template>
    </BottomNavigation>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        tabs: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },
    created () {
    },
    methods: {
        indexChange: function (args) {
            let newIndex = args.value
            let route = this.tabs[newIndex].route
            this.goToPage(route)
        },
        goToPage (route) {
            this.$navigator.navigate(route)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think the bottom navigation yet supports dynamic tabs. The number of TabContentItem / TabStripItem should be static. If you need them dynamic, you may have to create them in JS. If you need routing inside each tab, use Frame and Page inside each TabContentItem.

Comment: In TabContentItem, I tried to use Frame and Page with some content, but it crashes without any error on console. But maybe you misunderstood me. I don't want to have routing inside tab content items, I just want to redirect to another page as soon as I tap a tab text.

Comment: I use NativeScript-Vue-Navigator plugin for routing by the way. Maybe I should do it without it.

Comment: "Using selectedIndexChange event I can redirect user to another page, but when one of the tab links is current page, it goes to infinite loop." --- If that is something that would work for you, why not check if that is the current page or include a parameter on the first redirect, and then check it to avoid an infinite loop.